# APIs for implementing video playback in embedded Linux (buildroot)

Tags: api, embedded-linux, libvlc, buildroot, video-player

I am working on an action-camera like device. I need to implement the functionality to play recorded videos. Namely, the playback ui should be able to play/pause, seek, 2x speed playback and display time/duration of the AVI file. SDL 1 is used for the graphics and Buildroot for building.

I like libvlc, but for some reason it is really slow on the target system.

To write my own video playback ffplay as a foundation is the viable alternative. I find it to be low-level compared to libvlc though.

Could you please suggest me libraries like libvlc that are promising for video playback implementation in embedded Linux?

Comment: Have you tried to profile `libvlc`? I would suggest to optimize it rather than reinvent a wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the gstreamer framework, if it has support for hardware acceleration on the target.